# Different firewall behavior between UdpClient and UdpClient(IPEndPoint)

Tags: c#, udp, firewall, udpclient

**First solution (working as expected)**

To send a broadcast over UDP I used the following simplified code block which worked as expected and did not triggered anything on the firewall. But the [UdpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/35kh3f39(v=vs.110).aspx) automatically chooses the most appropriate interface which is not always the right one.

```
const int udpPort = 11115;
var broadcastIpAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] {169, 254, 255, 255});
var broadcastEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(broadcastIpAddress, udpPort);

var udpClient = new UdpClient();
var message = new byte[] { 0xFF };
udpClient.Send(message, message.Length, broadcastEndpoint);
```

**Second solution (triggers firewall)**

Because of that I changed the code and explicitly select a NIC over the IP address. This approach also works but in contrast to the first solution it triggers a firewall popup. The firewall is triggered when the UdpClient class gets created.

```
const int udpPort = 11115;

var broadcastIpAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 169, 254, 255, 255 });
var broadcastEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(broadcastIpAddress, udpPort);

var localIpAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 169, 254, 1, 1 });
var localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(localIpAddress, udpPort);

var udpClient = new UdpClient(localEndpoint);
var message = new byte[] { 0xFF };
udpClient.Send(message, message.Length, broadcastEndpoint);
```

**Question(s):** Is there a way to prevent the firewall popup? And why is there a different behavior of the firewall in the two described procedures?

**Note #1:** Interestingly in both cases the returned data is received by Wireshark and code. No matter what I select in the firewall popup. Is this only because of the APIPA address range?

**Note #2:** The only difference I noticed between both solutions is that in the second solution the sent message will also be received by the sender which is not the case in the first solution.

**Note #3:** A different solution to explicitly select a NIC would also be gladly accepted as an answer.